Razer Blade Stealth 13 2017 RZ09 won’t charge. How can I repair it if I think I know what is damaged?
I have a Razer Blade Stealth 13 2017 RZ09 which won’t charge however powers on fine. I opened it up and I can see what I believe to be a damaged capacitor.
I can’t find a schematic for the laptop so I’m just wondering if there is a way I can determine the value of the capacitor so I can repair it?
Image of damaged capacitor next to USB-C port:


Have you contacted the company or attempted to measure the capacitance?

why don't you clean it first?

There's probably a few things I would suggest before trying to make conclusions: measure continuity between both ends of the capacitor, check if you can charge your laptop on other USB-C/barrel jack charging ports if there are any, check the circuitry that is actually responsible for charging your battery (i.e. your battery management circuitry).

Without the actual schematics and details on any broken component; hard to tell what value to pick for the replacement  - which might be important; or not (e.g. decoupling caps could actually just be removed and the thing would still work).
